# Converting class based component to functional component using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, react-hooks

I'm having a hard time trying to convert my component. My main confusion is the useState. In my class based component it's easy to update my state with `this.setState`, but with hooks I'm quite confused about how thats achieved?

for example I can do this

```
onDrag = (event, item, currentDropZoneId, currentDropZoneItems) => {
event.preventDefault();
console.log("source", currentDropZoneId);
this.setState({
  dragSource: currentDropZoneId,
  draggedItem: item
});
```

};

and then use it my JSX

```
<Item
 draggable
 onDrag={event => this.onDrag(event, item, dropZone.id)}
 ey={item.id}
 />
```

How do I achieve the same functionality but with hooks?  What is `this.setState` equalivent in react hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options to achieve updating state values with hooks:

- the first option would be to declare 2 state variables (or more, depending on the needs of the component)

```
...
const [dragSource, setDragSource] = useState(...);
const [draggedItem, setDraggedItem] = useState(...);
...

const onDrag = (event, item, currentDropZoneId, currentDropZoneItems) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("source", currentDropZoneId);
  setDragSource(currentDropZoneId);
  setDraggedItem(item);
}

...

<Item
 draggable
 onDrag={event => onDrag(event, item, dropZone.id)}
 ey={item.id}
 />
```

- the second option would be to create a single state variable for all the fields

```
...
const [state, setState] = useState({
  dragSource: ...,
  draggedItem: ...
});
...

const onDrag = (event, item, currentDropZoneId, currentDropZoneItems) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log("source", currentDropZoneId);
  setState({
    dragSource: currentDropZoneId,
    draggedItem: item
  });
}

...

<Item
 draggable
 onDrag={event => onDrag(event, item, dropZone.id)}
 ey={item.id}
 />
```

Keep in mind that you no longer need to use 'this' keyword when invoking a function inside the current component, as the component is no longer a class, it became a function.